# How do I Align the products row by row instead of one per line in this products list page?

Tags: visualforce, css, html

This is a page with 4 products on it, it is being displayed one product line by line.

I want to display them row by row where each row covers at least 3 products.

How do i make that happen

below is my code

```
<apex:page controller="homepagebuttons" showHeader="false">

    <style>
             p{
                 font-size: 12px;
                 color:White;
              }

             h3{
                 font-size: 15px;
                 text-align:center;
                 color:White;
               }

               body{
    background-image:url("{!$Resource.BGcheck3}");
    background-repeat:repeat;
 }  



     </style>

        <apex:outputText value="{!Guestoruser}" style="float:right;font-weight:bold;color:white;text-align:right;" />
        <p style="font-size:19px;font-weight:bold;"> Products available today </p>


        <ul>
    <li>


            <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.Prod1}">
            <apex:image url="{!$Resource.Testprod1}" width="100" height="180"/><br/>
            <h3>Logo Shirt (Gray)</h3> 
            </apex:outputLink>
            <p>$20.00</p>

    </li>
    <li>
            <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.Prod1}">
            <apex:image url="{!$Resource.testprod2}" width="100" height="180"/><br/>
            <h3>Mike the Frog Shirt (Orange)</h3>
            </apex:outputLink>
            <p>$25.00</p>

    </li> 
    <li>
            <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.Prod1}">
            <apex:image url="{!$Resource.testprod3}" width="100" height="180"/><br/>
            <h3>Logo Shirt (Gray)</h3>
            </apex:outputLink> 
            <p>$20.00</p>

    </li>
    <li>
            <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.Prod1}">
            <apex:image url="{!$Resource.testprod4}" width="100" height="180"/><br/>
            <h3>Mike the Frog Shirt (Orange)</h3>
            </apex:outputLink>
            <p>$25.00</p>

    </li> 
</ul>







</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, i would have been used bootstrap's grid system for such scenario, but for a quick solution something like below may work for you,

```
<apex:page controller="homepagebuttons" showHeader="false">

    <style>
             p{
                 font-size: 12px;
                 color:White;
              }

             h3{
                 font-size: 15px;
                 text-align:center;
                 color:White;
               }

               body{
    background-image:url("{!$Resource.BGcheck3}");
    background-repeat:repeat;
 }  

div.item{
        width:33%;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    div.container{
        width:100%;
    display:block;
    }

     </style>

        <apex:outputText value="{!Guestoruser}" style="float:right;font-weight:bold;color:white;text-align:right;" />
        <p style="font-size:19px;font-weight:bold;"> Products available today </p>


        <div class="container">
    <div class="item">


            <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.Prod1}">
            <apex:image url="{!$Resource.Testprod1}" width="100" height="180"/><br/>
            <h3>Logo Shirt (Gray)</h3> 
            </apex:outputLink>
            <p>$20.00</p>

    </div>
    <div class="item">
            <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.Prod1}">
            <apex:image url="{!$Resource.testprod2}" width="100" height="180"/><br/>
            <h3>Mike the Frog Shirt (Orange)</h3>
            </apex:outputLink>
            <p>$25.00</p>

    </div> 
    <div class="item">
            <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.Prod1}">
            <apex:image url="{!$Resource.testprod3}" width="100" height="180"/><br/>
            <h3>Logo Shirt (Gray)</h3>
            </apex:outputLink> 
            <p>$20.00</p>

    </div>
    <div class="item">
            <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.Prod1}">
            <apex:image url="{!$Resource.testprod4}" width="100" height="180"/><br/>
            <h3>Mike the Frog Shirt (Orange)</h3>
            </apex:outputLink>
            <p>$25.00</p>

    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi erkan, it worked, thanks. If you may please explain the solution, i am new to all this.

Comment: Actually, nothing special, a basic css rules, check the item class. I just put 33 harcoded, if you want 4 columns , you would need to put 25 and so on.

Comment: is there a better way to code this, i mean with my version of code with the list tags, should i just use everything in css and then use, also where can I learn nicely about <div> and bootstrap's grid system , if you could provide your favorite links about them, i tried to learn learn on both but couldn't understand so if you could provide any link.Thanks again Erkan

Comment: for such scenario, the list does not work, you have to use div and grid system.  Check the link. 
https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/